# Error mentioning LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I moved my project from my computer to another computer,
and when I opened it I was faced with this problem with LINQ:

[image]

> Expression of type System.Data.Linq.Table(Of Homework) is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.

Please, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing

```
Import System.Linq
```

or a reference to `System.Core.dll`. I can't see why that would have happened just from moving to a different computer though...

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you're on another computer--does that computer have .NET 3.0+ installed on it?  If not, then you won't be able to address System.Linq until it's installed.